# Getting a piece of information from development GAE server to local filesystem

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an application I am developing on top of GAE, using Python APIs. I am using the local development server right now. The application involves parsing large block of XML data received from outside service.

So the question is - is there an easy way to get this XML data exported out of the GAE application - e.g., in regular app I would just write it to a temp file, but in GAE app I can not do that. So what could I do instead? I can not easily run all the code that produces the service call outside of GAE since it uses some GAE functions to create the call, but it would be much easier if I could take the XML result out and develop/test the parser part outside and then put it back to GAE app.

I tried to log it using `logging` and then extract it from the console, but when XML is getting big it doesn't work well. I know there's bulk data import/export APIs but seems to be an overkill for extracting just this one piece of information to write it to data store and then export the whole store. So how to do it in the best way?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to get a copy of the output of part of your code for debugging purposes, correct? If the request is an interactive one, you could just return it in the response body. If it's not normally interactive, you could run it as one for the purposes of debugging. Or, failing all that, email it to yourself using the mail API.

Comment: @Nick The problem is that the request that does that already outputs other stuff, so I'd have to write a new one and have it do the same thing but without the output part. Which is possible, but seems a bit much work for debug, I was hoping for something simpler... But actually blobstore worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about writing the XML data to the blobstore and then write a handler that uses send_blob to download to your local file system?

You can use the files API to write to the blobstore from you application.

Comment: Yes, that probably would work. I hoped for something easier, but if I don't find anything simpler I'll probably do that.

Comment: Well if you were running it in the production server you could write it to Google storage and then use gsutil or the web console to download the file, which I guess would be slightly easier.